# Подскажите программу для position:absolute верстки

Tags: html, css

Существуют ли какие-то программы, расширения в ide, конструкторы, sketch/ps/figma to html или лайфхаки для того, чтобы сверстать приведенную в пример конструкцию на posiiton:absolute блоках. Я хочу сделать интерактивную иллюстрацию из более 100 SVG/PNG запчастей и не хотелось бы вручную координаты прописывать (zeplin конечно да, но это все-таки только наполовину решает задачу)

[image: макет]

Comment: любой векторный редактор

Comment: @MaximLensky а можно пример, как оттуда сделать импорт в html?

Comment: save as name.svg в любом векторном редакторе вот такая опция ...посмотрите ответы по svg на ru.stackoverlow.com в которых svg в 70% случаях из редактора svg

Comment: хотя можно и руками нарисовать такую штуку

Comment: @MaximLensky я похоже криво вопрос задал, но мне не нарисовать или сохранить в svg нужно, а сверстать div-ами несколько десятков изображений абсолютно их позиционируя между собой и сохраняя порядок слоев (z-index)

Comment: тогда только виссивиг редактор какой не будь... если не руками имею ввиду

Comment: svg лучше для этого

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mdeJdbE  на svg пример

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нарисовал один квадратик, остальное пошло по инерции)) Откройте в полноэкранном*

При каждом клике z-index тупо увеличивается на 1, но перед копированием идет сортировка по индексу и z-index везде удаляется, т.к. блоки и так перекрывают один-другого, в зависимости от последовательности в HTML.

UPD: Добавлена возможность ввести массив картинок.

```js
const id = (str) => document.getElementById(str);

addBlockOnClick();

setDragAndDrop();
setResize();
setColorFeatures();
setDeleteFeatures();
insertImageArray();

setCopyFeature();

/***/

function addBlockOnClick() {
  id('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let showDelBtns = id('delete-mode').dataset.showState || "";

    let div = (
      '<div class="item" style="background-color: RGB(0, 0, 0);">' +
        '<div class="delete' + showDelBtns + '">X</div>' +
        '<div class="resize"></div>' +
      '</div>\n\n'
    );

    id('mama').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', div);
  });
}

function setDragAndDrop() {
  let zIndex = 0;
  let drag = {
    start: false,
    elem: null,
    mouseOffset: {
      x: null,
      y: null,
    }
  };

  id('mama').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (drag.elem) drag.elem.classList.remove('active');

    if (!e.target.matches('.item')) return;
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    drag.start = true;
    drag.elem = e.target;
    drag.mouseOffset = {
      x: e.pageX - rect.left,
      y: e.pageY - rect.top,
    };

    e.target.classList.add('active');
    e.target.style.zIndex = zIndex++;
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    drag.start = false;
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (!drag.start) return;

    let x = e.pageX - drag.mouseOffset.x;
    let y = e.pageY - drag.mouseOffset.y;

    drag.elem.style.left = x + 'px';
    drag.elem.style.top = y + 'px';
  });
}

function setResize() {
  let resize = {
    elem: null,
    elemRect: {
      x: null,
      y: null,
    }
  };

  id('mama').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.resize')) return;

    let elem = e.target.parentNode;
    let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    resize.start = true;
    resize.elem = elem;
    resize.elemRect = {
      x: rect.left,
      y: rect.top,
    };

    elem.classList.add('active');
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    resize.start = false;
    resize.elem = null;
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (!resize.start) return;

    let width = e.pageX - resize.elemRect.x + 4;
    let height = e.pageY - resize.elemRect.y + 4;

    if (width * height < 100) return;

    resize.elem.style.width = width + 'px';
    resize.elem.style.height = height + 'px';

    resize.elem.dataset.size = width + ' x ' + height;
  });
}

function setColorFeatures() {
  (function updateInputFromDiv() {
    id('mama').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let item = e.target.closest('.item');
      if (!item) return;

      let rgb = item.style.backgroundColor.match(/rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/i);
      updateUserInput(rgb);

      /***/

      function updateUserInput(rgb) {
        rgb = rgb || ["full-match", 0, 0, 0];

        let input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');

        input.forEach((el, i) => {
          el.nextElementSibling.textContent = el.value = rgb[i+1];
        });
      }
    });
  })();

  (function updateDivFromInput() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]').forEach(function(inp) {
      inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
        let info = this.nextElementSibling;

        let active = document.querySelector('.item.active');
        if (!active) {
          info.textContent = "Блок не выбран!";

          return setTimeout(() => {
            if (info.textContent === "Блок не выбран!") {
              info.textContent = "";
            }
          }, 2000);
        }

        info.textContent = this.value;

        active.style.backgroundColor = getInputRGB();

        /***/

        function getInputRGB() {
          let input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');

          let rgb = [...input].map(e => e.value).join(", ");

          return "RGB(" + rgb + ")";
        }
      });
    });
  })();
}

function setDeleteFeatures() {
  id('delete-mode').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('#mama .delete').forEach(el => {
      el.classList.toggle('show');
    });

    this.dataset.showState = this.dataset.showState === " show" ? "" : " show";
  });

  id('mama').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.delete')) {
      e.target.parentNode.remove();
    }
  });
}

function setCopyFeature() {
  id('copy').addEventListener('click', autoCopy);

  function autoCopy() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = id('mama').innerHTML;
    
    let active = div.querySelector('.item.active');
    if( active ) active.classList.remove('active');
    
    let items = div.querySelectorAll('.item');
    
    items.forEach(item => item.innerHTML = "");
    
    items = [...items].sort((a,b) => {
      return parseInt(a.style.zIndex) - parseInt(b.style.zIndex);
    }).map(item => {
      return item.outerHTML.replace(/data-size=".*?"\s?|z-index:.*?(;\s?|(?="))/g, "");
    });        

    copy.call(this, items.join("\n\n"));

    /***/
    
    function copy(str) {
      let area = document.createElement('textarea');
      document.body.appendChild(area);

      area.value = str;
      area.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');

      let save = this.textContent;

      this.textContent = "Скопирован!";
      setTimeout(_ => this.textContent = save, 2000);

      area.remove();
    }
  }
}

function insertImageArray() {
  id('images').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let images = prompt("Введите адреса картинок через запятые или пробелы:");
    
    if(!images) return;

    let showDelBtns = id('delete-mode').dataset.showState || "";
    images = images.split(/,\s?|\s/).map(img => {
      return (
        `<div class="item" style="background-image: url('` + img + `');">` +
          '<div class="delete' + showDelBtns + '">X</div>' +
          '<div class="resize"></div>' +
        '</div>\n\n'
      );
    });

    id('mama').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', images.join(""));
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* Это важно для background-image, остальное ниже - декорация */
}

#mama {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  border: 1px solid red;  
  user-select: none;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  cursor: move;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item::after {
  content: attr(data-size);
  color: white;
  
}

.resize {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  right: -11px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  background-color: #f70;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  cursor: nw-resize;
}

.delete {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  
  padding-top: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delete.show {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f70, 2px 2px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">+ Блок</button>
<button id="images">>> Массив картинок</button>
<button id="delete-mode">Режим Удаления</button>
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
  R <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0"><span></span><br>
  G <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0"><span></span><br>
  B <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0"><span></span>
</div>

<button id="copy">Скопирвать код</button>

<div id="mama"></div>
```

Comment: Для айтема еще стоит установить background-color: transparent, чтобы массив корректно отрабатывал с прозрачными картинками. Работает идеально, я восхищен)

Comment: Крутая работа )